# ASP.NET SQLMembership Provider not logging in

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, sqlmembershipprovider

My web app uses the sql memebership provider. Running it locally all is well, deploying to a dev server it works fine too in firefox, but in IE8 something unexpected is happening.

Once a user logs in they're supposed to be redirected to home.aspx. What's happening when I attempt to login is it appears to accept the login credentials but then doesn't redirect to home.aspx. Instead it just redirects me to the login page as though I had attempted to access home.aspx directly without being logged in. The url parameter ReturnUrl is appended, Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fhome.aspx

Why is this only happening with IE8?

My local PC is IIS7 but the server is IIS6. Using the same web.config

Full code behind

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text))
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(tbUsername.Text, false);
            }
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbUsername.Text, false);
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ASPNET_DB" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ASPNET_DB" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
        <providers>
            <add name="SqlRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNET_DB" applicationName="/"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MYAPP.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="AccountManager"/>
        <allow roles="Client"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="AccountManager"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: And what about after you have logged in? Can you navigate to home.aspx manually (i.e. has the login actually worked and it is just the redirect failing?)

Comment: nope I'm just redirected to Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fhome.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a Cookies issue then? Maybe try running Fiddler to monitor the traffic in Firefox where it works and contrast with IE. http://www.fiddler2.com/

Comment: In my code I'm using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe) and that's the second-to-last thing that happens when an IE8 user signs in. Im also using if(!IsPostBack) { Log("Logout"); FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); } in the Page_Load. And the very last log entry I get is "Logout".  IE8 is doing a page refresh when I set the Auth Cookie.

Comment: you need to provide both the complete codebehind of login and the complete web.config.

Comment: Done, as above. IE is clearly not remembering cookies because when I add cookieless="UseUri" to the Forms authentication section IE works fine